# Как найти место в коде где был определён данный стиль?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[image: пример]

Помогите найти место в коде где был определён стиль, дающий border-bottom. Этот элемент был создан с помощью vue.js.

Задать этот стиль заново нельзя, т.к он уже где-то есть в коде. Хочу убрать чёрный бордер.

Comment: В приведенном вами коде `border-bottom` нигде не устанавливается. Ищите в `css`. Обычно в `DevTools` в хроме можно посмотреть, где данный стиль прописан - напротив селектора в `Elements->Styles`

Comment: А что, так трудно открыть проект через любой файловый проводник(например папка винды) или через Total commander и найти файл в котором есть данная строка...

Comment: @Arsen Стиль задаётся через фреймворк vuetify , и html это интерпретирует уже в свои стили .Ну и то, что сгенерировал html, понятное дело, не ищется в проекте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Задать этот стиль заново нельзя, т.к он уже где-то есть в коде. Хочу убрать чёрный бордер.

Задать то нельзя, а переопределить свойство border-bottom используя более сложную связку тегов для приоритета и добавив !important вполне можно)

на примере это где-то так :

```
body .table .theme--light.v-data-table thead tr:last-child th {
   border-bottom:none !important;
}
```

Но если нужно именно заменить старый (можно посмотреть в браузере где его расположение)  Stepan Kasyanenko сказал уже об этом в комментарии.

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать !important, особенно здесь. Epileptic kid правильно делает, что интересуется где именно прописана рамка - нужно не перебивать/наслаивать/и т.д., а менять стили, если так поставлена задача.